# boost file_mapping exception

Tags: c++, boost

The code crashes for an unknown reason. I really have no idea why, I tried running this on another computer and even starting a new project but nothing. I also recompiled boost.

```
try
{
    cout << "A " << file_name << endl;//fine
    file_mapping m_file(file_name, read_only);
    mapped_region region(m_file, read_only);
} catch (interprocess_exception e)
{
    cout << "B|" << file_name << "| ";//empty???
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

The filename is 100% valid, `const char*`, the codes outs:

```
A C:\file
B || The system cannot find the file path specified.
```

But the thing is: this happens only **some times**, the others work ok!

Comment: permissions? locks? dieing/stuck processes?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wait `file_name` points to stale data.

Try changing `filename` to a `std::string`. And be ***sure*** that the `const char*` is still valid at the point where you initialize `filename`.

Most likely, the `const char*` points to a (stack) location that no longer exists.

If you compile with full warnings enabled you might find where this happens (when the compiler reports "returning a reference to local", e.g.)